# How to add infinite loop slider with Time interval using iScroll in phonegap?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

In my project I am using iOS Phonegap and I am new to this phonegap. I want scroller like iScroll which roll infinite loop.I have gone through these links:[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974285/how-to-create-infinite-iscroll)but din't get any hint.
As per my knowledge i added this javascript on top

```
function getStartTimerNext(){
var loopnext= myScroll.scrollToPage('next', 0);return false
}, 3000);}
getStartTimerNext();
```

It's working upto end of the last item,then stuck there.
Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray... I solve this issue myself..
I added two functions  in my code and call it one after another. See below code:

```
function getStartTimerNext(){
var loopnext= myScroll.scrollToPage('next', 0);return false
}, 4000);}

function previousPageLoop(){
setInterval(function () {
myScroll.scrollToPage(0,0);
}, 12500);
}
getStartTimerNext();
previousPageLoop();
```

After that It's working Properly.. :)

Answer (score 0):

another simple method to solve infinite loop in iscroll is define function which contain sequentially select pages. and after last page get first page like

```
function nextPage(){

        if(myScroll.currPageX == totalPages){
            myScroll.scrollToPage(0, 0);
        }else{
            myScroll.scrollToPage('next', 0);return false
        }            
    }
```

totalPages will be total no. of pages want to scroll.
call this function in setInterval on your demand 3sec or 4sec.

```
setInterval(function() {  nextPage(); }, 4000);
```

and Solved!!!